# Where to put 'created_by' reference in database?

Tags: database-design, associations

My database consists of **users** and **projects**. A **user** can create a **project** and a **project** can have multiple **members** (**users**). The **creator** of a **project** is a **member**, too. I came up with two solutions to this problem.

Which one of the following two options should i prefer, and is there any other better (i dont like both) solution?

**OPTION 1:**

```
User:
    id: int (PK)

Project_Member:
    user_id: int (FK -> User.id)
    project_id: int (FK -> Project.id)

Project:
    id: int (PK)
    created_by: int (FK -> User.id)
```

**OPTION 2:**

```
User:
    id: int (PK)

Project_Member:
    user_id: int (FK -> User.id)
    project_id: int (FK -> Project.id)
    is_creator: bool

Project:
    id: int (PK)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option 1 is **better** than option 2 and it is **best** solution to your **current** problem in my idea.

**First**: In option 2, you have a lot of **Nullification** or **Redundancy**. For example if you have 1000 project and each project have 100 members, then you have 100000 records in `Project_Member` and only 100 records have the value `is_creator` and the other is `NULL`. However if you set `True` or `False` to `is_creator`, it a type of **Redundancy** in your database design.

**Second**: In more cases (of our application) we need to show only the project manager (not members). In that cases the option 1 has better performance in comparison with option 2.

**Third**: In option 2, you need to set another **Constraint** that check each project should have **only one creator** and avoid to insert many creators to a specific project.